# Using AMD GPU with Theano, Torch

Tags: python, gpu, theano, torch

I understand that to use the GPU on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC I have to install a library like CUDA or Opencl.

The inxi command gives:

```
System:    Host: xxxxxx Kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   Mobo: Dell model: 0AM6R0 version: A00 Bios: Dell version: A00 date: 11/19/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U CPU (-HT-MCP-) clocked at 2481.750 MHz 
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics 
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] 
           X.Org: 1.18.3 drivers: ati,radeon,intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
Network:   Card: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi 
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (5.6% used)
Info:      Processes: 315 Uptime: 2:09 Memory: 8697.8/15959.9MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 1.9.17
```

What steps I have to do to use the GPU? I already installed CUDA (I guess it is of no use since I have AMD card).

The python interpreter gives:

```
>>> print theano.config.device
cpu
```

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#gpuarray-backend

Comment: @talonmies i followed the instructions http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html